# Find and Replace ':' colon gives "That function isn't valid" error on Replace All

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

When I try to use Find and Replace in Excel 2013 by entering a colon into the 'Find what' field and any text into the 'Replace with' field I get "That function isn't valid" error on clicking 'Replace All'.

[image]

[image: That function isn't valid]

I am guessing that the colon is some kind of special character or something. Is there an escape character or a certain type of quotation marks or square brackets I should be using?

**Update**
I think it might relate to the fact the field starts with an @ symbol. But I want that there, I just don't want the colon at the end

**Update 2**

Thanks @Jerry I did try using a tilde and it does find the cells as before but also as before the same error message shows. Interestingly if I delete the colon myself in the cell then hit Enter, the same error message shows

Comment: Perhaps. I don't have Excel-2013 but it works fine on 2010. Try using find: `~:`. The `~` is the escape character in excel.

Comment: @Jerry I think it is all down to have an @ at the beginning of the cell

Comment: Possibly, you could maybe try to convert the column first into text so that no function can be evaluated?

Comment: @CodeBlend: Normally a single quotation mark `'` is the escape character.

Comment: @James not for the likes of Find and Replace, in that case it is a tilde `~` as @Jerry said

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cells need to have a single quote at the beginning in order to tell Excel to not interpret them literally.

Try this:

1. Highlight column B by clicking the column header
2. Open the **Search and Replace** dialog.
3. In the **Find what** textbox, enter `@`
4. In the **Replace with** textbox, enter `'@` (an at sign preceded by a single quote)
5. Click **Replace All**
6. Do the search and replace you were originally attempting.

Answer (score 1):

It does seem to have something to do with the @ as first symbol in a cell. I hd the same issue and tried the find and replace without selecting the few cells containing and starting with the @ sign. It worked.